# no suitable method found for write(object) error in MultiDimensional Vectors in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, vector, filewriter

I am using multidimensional vector. Whenever I wanna write the elements in a file, write() gets error saying "no suitable method found for write(object)".
Can you tell me how should I convert Integer object to int so that i can put that in file. 
Here is the code.

```
Vector<Vector> vectorA= new Vector<Vector>(1);
Vector<Integer> vectorB= new Vector<Integer>(1);

vectorB.add(1);
vectorA.add(v1);

File f=new File("A1-out1.txt");
f.createNewFile();
FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(f);
writer.write(vectorA.get(0).get(0));
```

Comment: Have you first looked this up in the [FileWriter Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)? This should be answerable with a quick view of this important document, no?

Comment: I have seen, but I am trying to put my value in that vector. How to do that? How i should convert Integer object to int?

Comment: A Writer writes String / char data. If you want to write an int, you need to either convert it to a String or not use a Writer and instead use a more general data output stream.

Answer (score -1):

There are no write methods on FileWriter that take an Object.  There are methods that take String, characters represented as integers, and a couple of others.

Here are the javadocs of interest: [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write-int-), and [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-).

I think the following code is more of what you're looking to do...  Hopefully.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Vector<Vector<Integer>> vectorA = new Vector<>();
    Vector<Integer> vectorB = new Vector<>();

    vectorB.add(1);
    vectorA.add(vectorB);

    File file = new File("A1-out1.txt");
    file.createNewFile();

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

    fileWriter.write(vectorA.get(0).get(0).toString());
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: `writer.write(vectorA.get(0).get(0).intValue());` won't this write the int as if it were a char with that int value? I doubt that the OP really wants his data written to file this way.

Comment: So to make it concrete, his int data vector holds a value of 65 as one of its many values, and you're suggesting that he write an `A` char to his file?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  That is what I get for not reading the docs as closely as I should have...  Updated my answer.